# Trigonometric integral $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{\omega}}\sin(\omega t)\cos(n\omega t)\,dt$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

How can I get the value of this integral?
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{\omega}}\sin(\omega t)\cos(n\omega t)\,dt$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$\sin p\cos q=\dfrac{\sin(p+q)+\sin(p-q)}{2}$

Comment: I thing the relative sign is $-$, not $+$. Bur apart from that, why has somebody downvoted the answer? He/she should explain it.

Comment: It is a + sign.

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry.

Comment: It wasn't me, but: Some people downvote answers to off-topic questions.  This one is off-topic in the sense of needing additional explanation.